# "Forced constness" in std::map<std::vector<int>,double> >?

Tags: c++

Consider this program:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;
typedef std::map<IntVector,double> Map;
void foo(Map& m,const IntVector& v)
{
   Map::iterator i = m.find(v);
   i->first.push_back(10);
};
int main()
{
   Map m;
   IntVector v(10,10);
   foo(m,v);
   return 0;
}
```

Using g++ 4.4.0, I get his compilation error:

```
test.cpp: In function 'void foo(Map&, const IntVector&)':
test.cpp:8: error: passing 'const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' as 'this' argument of 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]' discards qualifiers
```

I would expect this error if I was using `Map::const_iterator` inside foo but not using a non-const iterator.

What am I missing, why do I get this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keys in a map are constant. A map is a tree, and you can't just going around changing the keys or you'll break its invariants. The `value_type` of a map with `Key` and `Value` is `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, to enforce this.

Your design needs some changing. If you really need to modify the key, you need to remove the element, change its key, and re-insert it with the new key.

Also concerning your example specifically, you will get undefined behavior (if this did work). Your map is empty when you call `foo`, so the iterator returned by `find` will be `m.end()`; the element doesn't exist. But then you'd go on to modify this non-existent element: ka-boom. Whenever you `find` something, you should check that it was found before you attempt to use it.

Comment: Thank you.  Sometimes you can't see the forest because all the trees are in the way. :-)